# fragment of fragments toolbar title setting

Tags: android

I have one Activity and lots of fragments switch between this Activity, i set the toolbar title just in this Activity , like this :
this Activity:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    if (id == R.id.logIn){
        switchFragment(LogInFragment.newInstance());
        //when i switch fragment , i change the tile by this code
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.pageLogIn);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    if (id == R.id.singUp){
        switchFragment(SignUp.newInstance());
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.singUp);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}

private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.mainFrame, fragment, null);
    //transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

and this my Activity layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.taiwandigestionsociety_v11.MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">



        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle"
            android:background="@drawable/actionbar">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainFrame"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header">
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My question is one of fragments has a button that it will switch to new fragment, i can't switch the toolbar title by the Activity java .

I try another way to set the function to call the Activity switch function, the app will crash .

I try like this:

```
public class Welcome extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        if (id == R.id.welcomeLogin){
            MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity();
            mainActivity.switchFragment(ActivityHomePage.newInstance());
        }
    }
}
```

How can i set the fragment toolbar title like those fragments ?

Comment: Hy please check my ans, i'kn but try this code.

Comment: (getActivity()).setTitle("This Activity");
 put this in your fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create One Method in Activity :**

```
 public void setToolBar(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
   }
```

**And call this method in `onCreateView` of Fragment :**

```
  ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setToolBar(title);
```

Comment: thanks @Mavya Soni , i got it now , you solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create `instance` of `Activity` like this! Rather pass your `context` of `MainActivity` to the `Fragment` then use that to change.

```
 - MainActivity mainActivity=new MainActivity();
 - mainActivity.switchFragment(ActivityHomePage.newInstance());
```

Comment: i imitate by other source code , thanks your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

First of defined main activity

```
private HomeActivity activity;
```

after set values "onCreate" method

```
activity = (HomeActivity) getActivity();
```

set toolbar values:

```
HeaderBar headerBar;
headerBar = (HeaderBar) view.findViewById(R.id.headerBar);
```

Example i hv set right side image in tital bar:

```
headerBar.ivRight.setImageResource(R.mipmap.save);
```

Comment: thanks for your advice , my problem is switch fragment toolbar title . No matter how i still appreciate with help.